# Oracle SQL/PLSQL: Return Boolean value when multiple criterion met across many rows of data

Tags: sql, oracle, boolean-logic

I have a query that currently returns multiple rows of data. I need to analyse this data using PL/SQL and/or SQL to determine whether it meets the business requirements - returning either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

```
Sample Data 1                 Sample Data 2               Sample Data 3

TYPE        STATUS            TYPE        STATUS          TYPE        STATUS  
Red         Open              Red         Open            Red         Open
Blue        Open              Blue        Open            Blue        Open
Yellow      Open              Yellow      Open            Yellow      Open
Red         Closed            Yellow      Closed
Red         Pending
```

Requirements - if met return `TRUE`, otherwise `FALSE`:

**The STATUS for each TYPE must be 'Open'.**

**If there is more than 1 record for the same TYPE then the STATUS on at least 1 record must be 'Open', the STATUS on the remaining records must be 'Closed'.**

Results based on requirements above:

```
Sample Data 1 = FALSE
Sample Data 2 = TRUE
Sample Data 3 = TRUE
```

Any and all help much appreciated, apologies if this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle SQL doesn't have boolean types, so let's use 0 and 1:

```
select type,
       (case when count(distinct case when status = 'open' then type end) = count(distinct type) and 
                  count(case when status = 'open' then type end) = count(distinct type) and
                  sum(case when status not in ('open', 'closed') then 1 else 0 end) = 0                 
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
from t
group by type;
```

The logic:

- The first condition says that each `type` has at least one "open".
- The second condition (combined with the first) says that each `type` has exactly one "open".
- The third condition says that the only status are "open" and "closed".

Comment: Oracle PL/SQL does have a Boolean data type, however as you have provided a SQL solution then it makes no difference in this context.

Comment: Also the second line of logic is incorrect: `count(case when status = 'open' then type end) = count(distinct type) and` - The 2nd requirement says AT LEAST ONE status must be 'Open', it does not say ONLY ONE.